# Windows 8 - Is there a way to activate multiple spell check providers?

Tags: c++, windows-8, spell-checking, provider

So I'm building my own spell check provider but it's rather a specific one to certain cases and doesn't correct all mistakes. Is there a way to spell check through my provider then forward the word to another provider ( Microsoft spell check )? This would be useful if anyone wants to extend Microsoft spell checker features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to be both a provider and a client, but there isn't a way to request a specific spell check provider when you are the client. That is controlled only by the user. I'm guessing from your question though that you want to support a specific case like legal or medical terms. If that's the case, you may want to consider just adding a word list of these terms and allowing the built in provider to handle.